# How to obtain CD information (burning speed, burning application etc.) in C#

Tags: c#, cd-rom, cd-burning

I've got a C# application and I'd like to implement some functionality of Nero Info Tool. It shows a lot of information about CD, but I actually need only two properties: application that was used to burn CD and burning speed.

I found only examples of CD burning libs and suggestions to use SPTI. I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Aside from SPTI, your only other option is IMAPI. There's an example available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx). Sometimes there's not a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SCSI.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've already asked author of library whether it can provide functionality that I need. Unfortunately, it can't :(